# Javascript desktop to mobile problem

Tags: javascript

Right Now I am trying to set up a image zoom and the abilty to drag a enlarged image around in a contained box. The code I have for the desktop is show in this fiddle [right here](http://jsfiddle.net/WpMyU/20/)

The main problem I have is when i run this js in a mobile enviroment everything works except the ability to move the image around. I am sure my problem is that I am using onmousemove instead of outouchmove, I did on another fiddle [right here](http://jsfiddle.net/u8Gt6/) that used that but still no dice.

So my question is am I not using ontouchmove right or if anyone has any suggestion it would be much helpful